# Applying a media query to jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, header

I'm trying to have my header (which has some jQuery applied to it) hidden on mobile.

I have a header which I've used jQuery to have slide in and out at a certain scroll point. It works well.

By default the header has display: none, the jQuery below makes the header visible.

I was hoping if I added a media query (for iphone) to hide the header with !important it would hide the header in all circumstances - but that hasn't had the desired effect.

jQuery (working fine):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll > 700 && scroll < 1000){
                $('#why-jquery').slideDown();
            }

            if (scroll < 700 && scroll < 1000){
                $('#why-jquery').slideUp();
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

main css:

```
#why-jquery {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
}
```

media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #why-jquery {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear. I don't understand your question. There is logic error in your `if`

Comment: if it's an error it's not causing any issues, would you kindly point out the error though for my education?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered your mistake. You are writing the correct code but there is a small problem in the way you have written your media query . **There is a small syntax problem.**

> So change your media query from:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px)
    #why-jquery {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

> to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
    #why-jquery {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Basically in your media query CSS a **{ was missing**.

Also Created a dummy example using your code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 700 && scroll < 1000) {
      $('#why-jquery').slideDown();
    }

    if (scroll < 700 && scroll < 1000) {
      $('#why-jquery').slideUp();
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#why-jquery {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  background: green;
}

.container {
  height: 1600px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){ #why-jquery {
  display: none !important;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="why-jquery"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, I was indeed missing a { but turns out my idea doesn't work - the jQuery is overriding the display:none !important;

Comment: you dont want header in the mobile version? can you share the link